# Snapping windows to pre-defined grids in GNOME

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, compiz

I would like to snap windows in GNOME (more specifically, under Ubuntu) to user pre-defined grids.

I have tried the "Snapping Windows" and "Grid" plugins for [Compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz), and have also seen demos of [PyWO](http://code.google.com/p/pywo/), but none of these tools seem to provide the above option.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried different window managers than metacity? [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) is an example and it is very customizable.

Comment: Thanks kmels, I'll give them a try, although I didn't see anything about window snapping in their site.

Comment: By the way, GNOME 3 seems to support "Window snapping" now. Check their demo videos.